# How does .Net get UTC?

Tags: .net, datetime, time

I am considering switching the time of our application from local to UTC.  However, someone asked the question how it calculated UTC and I don't know myself.  I did a search, but didn't see the answer anywhere.

Does it simply convert local time based on timezone?

If so, is there any way to account for a computer whose time is off and has no internet connection?  (I figure not, but thought I would ask anyway).

Comment: When you install the OS, the OS asks you where you are. This system time offset is how it defines local vs UTC

Comment: So if the time on the computer is off, UTC will be off too.  I figured, I just wanted to be clear.  Thank you.

Comment: @EatATaco yup. it does not require any internet connection.

Comment: Also, I suggest that you switch to [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/). It'll make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> how it calculated UTC

It is not calculated *at all*.  It is exactly the other way around, UTC is simple and it is local time that requires an Internet connection to accurately track daylight saving time transition rules.

Local time is entirely too ambiguous to reliably run an operating system on.  Windows' clock runs on UTC.  Also used for example for the various time stamps on files on your disk, your files don't suddenly get an hour older on a DST transition.

So [DateTime.UtcNow](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#b0d5e4c9a8d4ddac) directly pinvokes the GetSystemTimeAsFileTime() winapi function without massaging the returned value at all.  It is DateTime.Now that's difficult.  Clearly you don't want to hesitate to switch :)

Comment: To clarify, the internet connection is only required (read, the easiest way) to update the timezone and DST rules when changes occur.  An internet connection is not required to calculate UTC to local time.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the detailed response.  That makes a ton of sense and makes it much easier.